# Grouping into interval of 30 minutes to its nearest hour

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hello I am trying to group interval by 30 mins to the nearest hour. I am able to group by 30 mins but I am unable to make nearest hour logic work. I have attached a snapshot from which you can get an idea of what I want.

```
  select SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(price AS CHAR) ORDER BY `timestamp`), ',', 1 ) as open,
                    max(price) high,
                    min(price) low,
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(price AS CHAR) ORDER BY `timestamp` desc), ',', 1 ) as close,
                    coinrace.watch_list.symbol,
                    timestamp
                    from coinrace.watch_quote
                    join coinrace.watch_list on coinrace.watch_list.watch_id = coinrace.watch_quote.watch_id
                    where (`timestamp` between '2015-12-03' and '2015-12-10')
                    and coinrace.watch_quote.serial_number = 1
                    and coinrace.watch_quote.BuyOrSell='buy'
                    and coinrace.watch_list.symbol='MCOEUR'
                    group by  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) div (30*60)
```

[image: Please check this]

Comment: What about for `2015-12-06 20:58:23`?? Should be `2015-12-06 21:00:00` or `2015-12-06 20:30:00`?

Comment: Its near to 21 so 2015-12-06 21:00:00

Comment: Don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp values - [you'll sometimes get wrong results](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  You should be using an exclusive upper-bound (`<`) instead.  You may be able to construct an in-query virtual table for grouping.  You shouldn't include non-aggregate columns that aren't part of the `GROUP BY` - you get non-deterministic results.  I don't know for sure, but one of the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] options might serve you better for `open`/`close`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should select not just `timestamp`, but the value you are grouping by (`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) div 1800`), only you should also convert it back to a readable datetime value:

`from_unixtime((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) div 1800)*1800)`

So the query would  be like this:

```
  select SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(price AS CHAR) ORDER BY `timestamp`), ',', 1 ) as open,
                    max(price) high,
                    min(price) low,
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(price AS CHAR) ORDER BY `timestamp` desc), ',', 1 ) as close,
                    coinrace.watch_list.symbol,
                    from_unixtime((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) div 1800)*1800) as timestamp
                    from coinrace.watch_quote
                    join coinrace.watch_list on coinrace.watch_list.watch_id = coinrace.watch_quote.watch_id
                    where (`timestamp` between '2015-12-03' and '2015-12-10')
                    and coinrace.watch_quote.serial_number = 1
                    and coinrace.watch_quote.BuyOrSell='buy'
                    and coinrace.watch_list.symbol='MCOEUR'
                    group by  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) div (30*60)
```

Comment: It will also group accordingly. Like will it group from 7 to 7:30?

Comment: I did not change the grouping function, since it supposedly worked well, so it should work exactly as your previous query, only timestamp column will be different. I do not have MySQL installed to test it.